# Comparing two text files not giving required result

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a script to work with files of biometrics which start with '>' , but now i have a same text files without '>', i change my script but its not displaying the output.
This is my script

```
with open('input1.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    file1_data = dict(line.split(None, 2)[1::-1] for line in file1 if line.strip())
with open('input2.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in file2:
        if line[:1] == '>':
            row = line.strip().split('|')
            key = row[0][1:]
            if key in file1_data:
                output.writerow(row + [file1_data[key]])
        else:
            outputfile.write(line)
```

This is input1:

```
Q5 Bat Wood 
Q6 Ball Tough 
Q7 Pitch Dry
```

This was input2:

```
>Bat|Batsman
>Ball|Bowler
>Pitch|Cricket
```

So the program matches the second row of input1 with the 1st row of input2 and and if it match it attach the row1 of input1 with input2 , like `output`:

```
>Bat|Batsman|Q5
>Ball|Bowler|Q6
>Pitch|Cricket|Q7
```

But `Now` my `input2` file change to

input2:

```
Bat|batsman 8
Ball|bowler 4
Pitch|matches 9
```

Required output

```
Bat|batsman|Q5 8
Ball|bowler|Q6 4
Pitch|matches|Q7 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** to reflect change in output format required

Try this:

```
with open('input1.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    file1_data = dict(line.split(None, 2)[1::-1] for line in file1 if line.strip())
with open('input2.txt', 'rb') as file2, open('output.txt', 'wb') as outputfile:
    output = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='|')
    for line in file2:
        row = line.strip().split('|')
        key, n = row[0], ' '+row[1].split(' ')[1]
        if key in file1_data:
            row = [row[0], row[1][:row[1].find(' ')], file1_data[key] + n]
            output.writerow(row)
            print row
```

Comment: Check the required output. It has changed also, and it doesn't match your code's

Comment: @ChrisProsser kindly check the required output

Comment: @Wish_2_fly let me know if you have any questions about how this works.

Comment: @ChrisProsser sure if `key, n = row[0], ' '+row[1].split(' ')[1]`

Comment: Okay, this assigns values to key and n (you can list as many variables as you like so long as the number of results after the = is the same as the no of variables. Row[1].split(' ') splits the string in the second position (indexing starts at 0) into a list, treating each space as a  delimiter. [1] on the end takes the second value of this new list.